# Can someone explain some parts of this MIPS code to me?

Tags: string, assembly, char, mips

```
 1 .data
 2 msg1: .word 0:24
 3 .text
 4 .globl main
 5 main:
 6 li $v0, 8 #syscall for read str
 7 la $a0, msg1 #load address of msg1 to store string
 8 li $a1, 100 #msg1 is 100 bytes
 9 syscall
10 lb $t0, 5($a0) #load the character into $t0
11 li $t1, 'a' #get value of 'a'
12 blt $t0, $t1, nomodify #do nothing if letter is less than 'a'
13 li $t1, 'z' #get value of 'z'
14 bgt $t0, $t1, nomodify #do nothing if letter is greater than 'z'
15 addi $t0, $t0, -0x20 #encap the letter
16 sb $t0, 5($a0) #store the new letter
17 nomodify:
18 li $v0, 4 #syscall for print str
19 syscall
20 li $v0, 10 #system call for exit
21 syscall # we are out of here.
```

First off, the purpose of this code is to get a string from the user and print the string back.

My first question:

In line 10, why is it loading a byte from $a0 + 5 specifically? I get that $a0 is the input string that is to be printed, but I don't understand why it's offset by 5.

Second question:

In lines 11 - 14, why does it branch to nomodify if the character is less than 'a' or if the character is greater than 'z'? Isn't that just saying to print the character if it's not in the range of a-z?

Third question:

In lines 11-16, if the character is neither less than 'a' nor greater than 'z', line 15 says to add an immediate value of -0x20 into $t0, which the comment says is to "encap the letter". What does that mean?

Lastly:

the continued use of the word "char" is confusing me. This code is to read/print a string right? Isn't a char just one character of the string?

Comment: Re. 3rd question: uppercase characters in the ASCII table don't have bit 5 (0x20) set, whereas lowercase characters do. Example: "a" has value 0x61, and "A" has value 0x41.

Comment: _"the purpose of this code is to get a string from the user and print the string back"_. Who told you that? I'd say that its purpose (or, at least, what it _does_) is to read a string, change the case of the 6th character to uppercase if that character is a letter, and then print the string.

Comment: @Kenney so this line is basically saying to capitalize the character? But what if the input string isn't even a letter? Does that mean it accepts any char that isn't a lowercase a to z?

Comment: @Michael why the 6th character?

Comment: Because `5($a0)` is the sixth character of the string. You'd have to ask the person who wrote the code why they were interested in that character specifically.

Comment: Lines 10-17 are basically `if ( $a0[5] >= 'a' && $a0[5] <='z' ) $a0[5] -= 0x20`. So it only capitalizes if it is a lowercase character.

Comment: @Kenney Okay after running the program and testing some input strings it does encap the 6th character for some reason. I thought the initial purpose of this code was to just print some input string which is why I was confused about all these other commands. The real code to STRICTLY read/print an input string would be: (I'll just answer my question to show it)

Answer (score 0):

`1 .data
 2 msg1: .word 0:24
 3 .text
 4 .globl main
 5 main:
 6 li $v0, 8 #syscall for read str
 7 la $a0, msg1 #load address of msg1 to store string
 8 li $a1, 100 #msg1 is 100 bytes
 9 syscall`

`18 li $v0, 4 #syscall for print str
19 syscall
20 li $v0, 10 #system call for exit
21 syscall # we are out of here.`

This would be the true code to simply read/write an input string. The code in the question (lines 10 - 17 specifically) I asked was doing extra things to the 6th character.